The error {"error":"Service not found: save"}
I have made a custom proxy and a service which should take a portion of text and save the text and assign it with a unique ID based on a timestamp. When testing the service directly it seems to work as intended however, when testing the service via the proxy I am getting the error Invoke-WebRequest : {"error":"Service not found: save"} persistently.
How the save function is handled by proxy.js file:
app.post('/save', async (req, res) => {
    try {
       const response = await axios.post(`${config.statefulURL}/save`, req.body);
       res.json(response.data);
    }catch (error) {
       res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error saving text', details: error.message });
    }
});

Save functionality:
app.post('/save', (req, res) => {
    const { text } = req.body;
    if (!text) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Text is required to save.' });
    }
    const id = Date.now().toString();
    savedTexts[id] = text;
    res.json({ id, message: 'Text saved' });
});


What debugging have you done? Have you checked the runtime value of config.statefulURL? The Invoke-WebRequest suggests you're using Powershell so how exactly are you constructing the request?
